# how to replace part of a string in javascript and wait for the task to finish before continuing with rest of code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

```js
let searchKeyword = 'hi'
Array[lastIndex]= await Array[lastIndex].replace(searchKeyword,'user_id:12345,"email":mail') /*wait for this line of code to finish executing, before continuing on with rest of code */
logger.info('hi')
```

do i have to use promises, I tried using await but it says await has no affect on this type of expression. i have more code but this is just the basic idea I am trying to accomplish, I am still new with asynchronous programming and learn about await and promises

Comment: You don't need to await anything, those are all synchronous tasks, every line of code you will write after that will be executed only after the previous tasks have completed.

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous in the code you show.  Remove the `await`.  But, please don't use `Array` as a variable as that's an existing class name.  Pick a different name.

Comment: well i forgot to add i have it all inside an async function

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you don't have to await anything inside this function. You probably have to fix the problem at the call side.